# How to distinguish when user opened a game via FCM Push Notification and read its Custom Data?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented a FCM within my game (for a chat system) and now I am trying to understand how can I open a specific chat scene when user clicks on FCM chat notification?

I successfully send `custom data` with the notification but now I have to be able to read it only when user clicked on that chat notification.

Game is developed in Unity and available both on iOS and Android.

Is there some out of the box functionality or I have to dig into core Android and iOS code and make magic?

I never done something similar to that so I am stuck.

Someone can help maybe?

Thank you

I have tried to implement some custom logic in `onMessageReceived` callback but it aint working as expected - for example I wanted to save the `userId` in prefs of the person who sent message and then when I open my app to check that prefs value and do magic. But it is not good solution at all since multiple people can send you the message and I have no clue which Push Notification user clicked.